# What causes the difference in ranges of forces?

Tags: forces, particle-physics, weak-interaction, strong-force, carrier-particles

What causes the difference in ranges of forces? In other words, why  is it that the weak force acts only at small distances whereas the Coulomb force has a very large range?

Comment: The weak force is mediated by massive bosons. This massiveness defines the short range interaction. The strong force is mediated by gluons which are massless, however they carry charge which allows to interact with other gluons: [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57732/how-can-a-massless-boson-gluon-mediate-the-short-range-strong-force). Coulomb forces are mediated by photons, which are massless and chargeless. Therefore they won't decay.

Comment: We don't really understand what these forces are, but just how to measure them and make use of them.  We model these forces by carrier particles that transfer information and energy between the particles that feel the force between them.  One of the great mysteries here is not knowing what a particle is.  A quantum-level object has both wave and particle properties.  It really isn't either one.  Sometimes imagining it as a standard particle works best.  Sometimes imagining it as a standard wave works best.   Nothing on the scale of day-to-day life corresponds to a quantum object.